# Using NgRX root state in a lazy loaded module opened in a new window

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngrx

Bit of a complex problem here. I have a lazy loaded module, but when it opens, it is opened in an entirely new window using something like this:

`this.window = window.open(window.location.origin + '/wizard', 'Field Wizard', 'resizable,scrollbar');`

combined with my router module having this route:

`{ path: 'wizard', loadChildren: () => import('./edit-spec-wizard/edit-spec-wizard.module').then(m => m.EditSpecWizardModule) }`.

This works perfectly, window opens and module is displayed. Now, from what I can tell, the application is re-bootstrapped in this new window. I am using NgRX in my application and wanted to use it to communicate across windows as well. (i.e. main application dispatches an action & updates the store. Windowed module has selectors listening for this altered slice of state).

However, because I believe the new windowed module is re-bootstrapped, it has essentially a fresh copy of the state. It doesn't pick up changes via the selector.

So,

1) Is this assumption that opening a lazy loaded module in a new window re-bootstraps the application, essentially giving it a fresh copy of application state, correct?

2) If it is, is there any way the two can have the same shared application state using NgRX?

Thanks.

Comment: Opening *any* route of your application in a new browser window, or tab, gives you a completely new instance of the application, and anything that comes along with it, including state. If you want to have 2 instances of your application communicate with each other, think about using websockets to make that happen.

Comment: You can keep Ngrx state in sync across tabs/windows via local storage: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/keeping-browser-tabs-in-sync-using-localstorage-ngrx-and-rxjs-87de3bca4e2c